# Argument assignment not working?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
IF (@SP_ARGUMENT IS NULL )

SET @SP_ARGUMENT = (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM TEST_TABLE )

SELECT @SP_ARGUMENT AS ARGUMENT_VAL
```

The above is code fragment of my stored proc.

But when I send sp_argument is null, I want it to use the 1st ID from the TEST_TABLE for the further queries below, but not working. What I am doing wrong here?

Pls help.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Could you tell us what is the exact error your are getting, when you say not working? What output do you see? How are you invoking the Proc? Understand that EXEC MYPROC 'NULL' & EXEC MYPROC NULL are two different statements

Comment: The issue is the assginment that is expected is not working and it is still null and also the Begin End is very much part of my code, missed it in the above code fragment. Sorry for the poor formatting, i am posting here for the first time.

Comment: It works for me, are you sure that `@SP_ARGUMENT` is really `NULL` and that `SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM TEST_TABLE` doesn't return `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IsNull to do this:

```
Set @SP_ARGUMENT = IsNull(@SP_ARGUMENT, (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM TEST_TABLE ))

SELECT @SP_ARGUMENT AS ARGUMENT_VAL
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly control the flow of your T-SQL commands you need to wrap the `SET` statement in a [Begin/End statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx).

```
IF (@SP_ARGUMENT IS NULL )
BEGIN
SET @SP_ARGUMENT = (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM TEST_TABLE )
END
SELECT @SP_ARGUMENT AS ARGUMENT_VAL
```

Comment: Not necessarily, albeit good style. You only need `BEGIN..END` when you have more than one statement, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214(v=SQL.80).aspx This should not be the cause of the error.

Comment: oops sorry i missed out the begin end... the issue is with the assignment not working!